# pasar un html a php en variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

Quisiera pasar un valor de html a php

el siguiente ID suelta la palabra **felicitaciones**

```
<script>
var premiojson = {
        "premio": "Felicidades"
    };
var entregajson = "";

entregajson = "<font color='green'>" + premiojson.premio + "</font>";

var resiu = document.getElementById("info");
resiu.innerHTML = entregajson;
</script>
     

</div><div id='info'/>
```

Queria hacer esto pero no se imprime el texto

```
<?php 
$varrid = "<div id='info'/>";
$varri = $varrid;
echo $varri;
?>
```

Alguna sugerencia? Favor no suponer que se de ajax por que es demasiado poco lo que conozco

Comment: `PHP` es un lenguaje que se compila del lado del servidor. Si necesitas que `PHP` imprima algo en el `HTML` necesitas o recargar el documento o usar `Javascript` para realizar `AJAX`.

Comment: Juan Carlos, ¿podrías explicar más tu pregunta? ¿Quién escribe felicitaciones? ¿De dónde sale esa info? ¿Estas usando JS o sólo PHP? ¿Qué tanta experiencia tienes con PHP y JS? Por otro lado veo que tu HTML está mal definido, deberías tener: <div id="info"></div>

Comment: mas explicado que algo simple y facil no esta amigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**INTRODUCCION**

Flujo de un archivo PHP:

1. Un archivo .php es primero procesado por el servidor (sólo conoce lo
   que está en el PHP y no puede tomar variables de JS)
2. Una vez que PHP ha hecho su trabajo, lo envía a tu explorador
3. Tu explorador interpreta el JS, y no puede comunicarse (de inicio) con tu PHP

**COMENTARIOS - SOLUCION NAIVE**

No veo en tu flujo por qué necesitas usar PHP, la variable la tienes en JS y vas a imprimir en la misma página. Si ese es el caso tienes errores de sintaxis:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='info'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**:

```
<script>
#Genera el JSON
var premioJson = { "premio": "Felicidades"};
#Genera una cadena de texto (HTML) con el valor del JSON
jsonOutput = "<font color='green'>" + premioJson.premio + "</font>";
#Encuentra el elemento HTML
var printTag = document.getElementById("info");
#Imprime
printTag.innerHTML = jsonOutput;
</script>
```

**SOLUCION USANDO PHP (Webservice)**

Si quieres que la variable llegue a PHP tienes que enviarla de alguna forma al servidor, tienes varias opciones con sus pros y contras:

**Formulario**

Puedes poner un formulario `<form>` con un `<input hidden>` y al hacer un submit esto puede ser recibido por un php por medio de la variable $_POST o $_GET.

**AJAX**

Puedes hacer una llamada AJAX a un php; si utilizas la librería JQuery esto es muy sencillo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Envío inforamación**

```js
$.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "mi_servicio.php",
                    data: {dato : valor},
                    contentType: "JSON"
                }).done(function(response) {
                    //La información recuperada está en la variable response
                    //Al terminar la comunicación hago algo (imprimo)
                }).fail(function(){
                    //Si la comunicación falla hago algo
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Recibo e imprimo (Servicio) PHP**

```
<?php
// Lee la información que llega
$dataRecibida = $_POST["data"];
// Imprimo
echo $dataRecibida;
?>
```